# Regex to extract one or more numbers, when there is a match on another word

Tags: regex

I'm tearing my hair out with this one - it can't be this complicated, but have looked around on the internet and can't find the answer..

I have a string which could be either of the following:

- £300 - £325 per Day
- £300pd
- £300 - £350pd
- £300 - £325 per day
- £300.00-£325.00 per day

I want to extract the amount(s) from the string, but only when "day" or "pd" occurs in the string.

What i have so far is...

```
preg_match_all('/([0-9.]+).*(day|pd)/i', $string, $matches)
```

.. but it doesn't seem to pull out the 2nd amount. I could narrow it down to..

```
preg_match_all('/([0-9.]+)/', $string, $matches)
```

.. but then it would match those which didn't contain "day" or "pd".

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `/([0-9.]+).*(day|pd)/ig`   in regex, javascript in particular, the g flag pulls them all instead of just the first match... and the result is an array.  I dont knoow if all regex make use of the flags like 'i' or 'g', etc

Comment: @Fallenreaper - i'm using PHP, which doesn't use the "g", so instead you use preg_match_all - but thanks anyway :)

Comment: np.  Was trying to ponder, but i forgot the PHP ruleset for regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lookahead instead:

```
if ( preg_match_all('/[0-9.]+(?=.*?(?:day|pd))/i', '£300.00-£325.00 per day', $matches) )
   print_r($matches[0]);
```

#### OUTPUT

```
Array
(
    [0] => 300.00
    [1] => 325.00
)
```

Comment: Perfect, I did have a look at lookaheads but couldn't get them to work either - simply a lack of understanding. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
preg_match_all('/(?=£([0-9.]+).*(?:day|pd))/i', $string, $matches);
```

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately, but thanks anyway :)